# Design Professional JSP Pages

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

What are the best tools for design and edit jsp pages? Some professional HTML tools such as Adobe Dreamweaver don't support jsp codes and tags :(

Or what is another suitable technique for designing UI in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 1):

You don't design JSP pages.

> JavaServer Pages (JSP) is a technology that helps software developers
>   create dynamically generated web pages based on HTML

Ideally, the designers design the HTML with static data, and set a target for web developers, to achieve the design by adding the appropriate dynamic logic (showing data from the DB, responding adequately to request parameters etc)

This being said, there are java web component frameworks bundled with themes, e.g [JSF's implementation Primefaces](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/themeSwitcher.xhtml), but JSP in particular is design agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

you should use java [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)'s such as [eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) and [IntelliJIDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)